# How can I end all Live Activities?

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit, activitykit, widgetliveactivity

An app can have many Live Activities simultaneously; I am trying to kill them all by doing the following.

```swift
for activity in Activity<MyAttributes>.activities {
  Task {
    await activity.end(nil, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
  }
}
```

But this doesn't affect the activities that continue being displayed.

Comment: just a shot in the dark but TaskGroup is probably a better alternative

Answer (score 1):

Can you try two things:

1. Add an @MainActor in your async context (I don't know if you're working in a main actor isolated view model)
2. Add a final value for your `MyAttributes` instead of `nil`